# Renaming points in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, points

I have a collection of new points `i,j,k,l` with their coordinates `(1953.2343076828638, 730.0513627132909), (1069.4232335022705, 5882.057343563125),(2212.5767664977293, 3335.942656436875),(4386.765692317136, 1318.948637286709)`.

I'm trying to give these points some names as `s1,s2,s3,s4`.

Also,  create two separate lists one with just the point name `[s1,s2,s3,s4]` and the other one with point name and its coordinate as `[s1:(1953.2343076828638, 730.0513627132909),(1069.4232335022705, 5882.057343563125)...]`

I have the following code for creating random points.

```
n = 10
#print(n)

#for k in n:
V = []
V=range(n)
#print("vertices",V)

# Create n random points

random.seed()

pos = {i:(random.randint(0,4000),random.randint(0,5000)) for i in V}
#print("pos =", pos)

points = []
positions = []
for i in pos:
    points.append(pos[i])
    positions.append(i)
    positions.append(pos[i])
```

Suppose I am forming a new list `L` with two existing points `4` and `7`.Then, `L = [4,7]`

When I type `L[0]` in the console it gives me, `4` and `pos[L[0]]` gives me its coordinates.

But considering my new list `K= [i,j,k,l]`, when I type `K[0]` in the console it gives me the coordinate, but not its name.

I need to add these points in `K` to the same list as `pos` defined above with their coordinates, but with different names. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: For the second part, might want to use dictionaries to keep a key and value together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access name and coordinates by index, use a list of tuples. Note that you need to name these explicitly. You should preferably avoid this step by using a list of tuples to store your name-coordinate pairs from the beginning.

To access by name, use a dictionary.

```
i, j, k, l = (1953.2343076828638, 730.0513627132909),\
             (1069.4232335022705, 5882.057343563125),\
             (2212.5767664977293, 3335.942656436875),\
             (4386.765692317136, 1318.948637286709)

K = [(name, var) for name, var in zip('ijkl', (i, j, k, l))]

## ACCESS BY INDEX
name_coord = K[0]  # ('i', (1953.2343076828638, 730.0513627132909))
name = K[0][0]  # 'i'
coord = K[0][1]  # (1953.2343076828638, 730.0513627132909)

## ACCESS BY NAME
d = dict(K)
coord = d['i']  # (1953.2343076828638, 730.0513627132909)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @jpp answer I would go for thing named `namedtuple`. Dictionaries usually tend to take more space than tuples.

```
from collections import namedtuple
coord = namedtuple('Coordinate', 'name coord')
i, j, k, l = (1953.2343076828638, 730.0513627132909),\
         (1069.4232335022705, 5882.057343563125),\
         (2212.5767664977293, 3335.942656436875),\
         (4386.765692317136, 1318.948637286709)

 K = [coord(name, var) for name, var in zip('ijkl', (i, j, k, l))]
```

It allows you to do then:

```
 c = K[0]
 print(c.name)
 print(c.coord)
```